# Authentication Failed On SonarQube 6.6 macOS Sierra

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis

Not able to login on Sonarqube local url http://localhost:9000 with default credentials admin/admin. When trying to login always getting this error message Authentication Failed.This only happen for SonarQube 6.6 version not for latest 7.0.On latest version 7.0 am able to login successfully but why am not able to login on 6.6 version.Before 2-3 months ago I was able to login on Sonarqube 6.6 but now what happened I don't know.Please help me.[Please find the attached log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/167q42LyB8LxvwIOvJ15YuRNiZvUGfT31/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add your web.log file so we can understand what's happening.

Comment: @EricHartmann Web.log file attached.

Comment: We have no permission to access the log file

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam you can access the log file now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your log files, you are using Java 9 or Java 10.
Using Java 8 will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks I know I installed idk 1.8 but by default jdk9 was default set.Also please mention this into your answer.

Comment: Note that the support of Java 9 has been fixed in SonarQube 6.7, which is the Long-Term Support version at the time of writing.